# Using rng('shuffle') function in parallel computing

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, random, parfor

I have a `parfor` loop for parallel computing in `Matlab`. I want have different random numbers in every calling of these `parfor`loops on 8 workers. If i don't use `rng('shuffle')` function i have same random number for `randperm(10)`. In this case my code run `rng('shuffle')` function before `randperm` at the same time in all workers. Have i different random numbers in this condition? when I see `randperm` outputs in parfor loop, Some of these outputs are same !

I need save `rng` before `rng('shuffle')` and use something likes `rng(saved_rng)` after ending parallel loop?

We have this in `Matlab` help :

> Note   Because rng('shuffle') seeds the random number generator based
>   on the current time, you should not use this command to set the random
>   number stream on different workers if you want to assure independent
>   streams. This is especially true when the command is sent to multiple
>   workers simultaneously, such as inside a parfor, spmd, or a
>   communicating job. For independent streams on the workers, use the
>   default behavior; or if that is not sufficient for your needs,
>   consider using a unique substream on each worker.

So what should i do? Have I different random numbers if i delete `rng`? I have two versions of these codes. One of them is calculation with `parfor` and other using `for` loop, Can i remove `shuffle` from `for` loop? I have different random numbers in this condition?

Thanks.

Ps.

I can have these structures:

```
parfor I=1:X
xx = randperm(10)
end


parfor I=1:X
rng('shuffle');
xx = randperm(10)
end

rng('shuffle');
parfor I=1:X
xx = randperm(10)
end
```

I want have different random numbers from `randperm` function. How can I do that? for `for` structure i need `shuffle` function (without it the random numbers are the same) but when i add it to `parfor` some random outputs of `randperm` are the same !

Comment: Why do you use `rng('shuffle')`? What is wrong with the default setting? Also, would it be possible to move the random generation to before the parallel part?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can we remove `rng('shuffle')` in `parfor`? Why we need `random generation` before `parfor loop`?

Comment: That does not really make it more clear for me. Could you include a simplified version of your code, clearly showing the problem?

Comment: Ok. I will add it to main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this properly, you need to choose an RNG algorithm that supports parallel substreams (in other words, you can split up the random stream into substreams, and each of the substreams still has the right statistical properties that you want from a random stream).

The default RNG algorithm (Mersenne Twister, or `mt19937ar`) does not support parallel substreams, but MATLAB supports two algorithms that do (the multiplicative lagged Fibonacci generator `mlfg6331_64` and the combined multiple recursive generator `mrg32k3a`).

For example:

`s = RandStream.create('mrg32k3a','NumStreams',4,'Seed','shuffle','CellOutput',true)`

`s` is now a cell array of random number substreams. All have the same seed, and you can record `s{1}.Seed` for reproducibility if you want.

Now, you can call `rand(s{1})` (or `randn(s{1})`) to generate random numbers from stream 1, and so on. Reset a stream to its initial configuration with `reset(s{1})`, and you should find that each stream is separately reproducible.

Each worker can then generate random numbers in a way that is still statistically sound, and reproducible even in parallel:

```
parfor i = 1:4
    rand(s{i})
end
```

For more information, look in the documentation for Statistics Toolbox under Speed up Statistical Computations. There are a few articles in there that take you through all the complicated details. If you don't have Statistics Toolbox, the documentation is online on MathWorks website.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I read somewhere that I should only should `randperm` in `parfor` without anything else. Because of running on workers, I have different random number streams with that in every `parfor` loop. can I do this? If not what is the problem?

Comment: You can use `randperm(s{i})` on the workers, as well as `rand`, `randn` and `randi`.

Comment: Why we can't only use `randperm`? Besides using `randperm` I have weight initialization of neural network with `configure` function. What should i do about that and why? thanks.

Comment: You can use `randperm`. But `randperm` on its own will be taking its randomness from the global random number stream which, unless you have modified it, uses a Mersenne Twister algorithm that does not support parallel substreams. So your code will not be reproducible when run in parallel, as you will not be able to control which worker gets which random numbers. I can't answer your second question - I have no idea how you're trying to parallelize neural networks. I would suggest you read the documentation to find out about issues in parallelizing random algorithms.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I `configure` and `train` a neural network in `parfor` loop but i want have different initial weights and biases in every `parfor` so i used `configure` in the the loop for weight initialization. I didn't find anything about random number generator of neural network. I think it will use `rng` (embed random generator of MATLAB).

Comment: + I'm calling my `parfor` loop again and again from another m-file. I should reset these structure in every calling? I want have different random numbers and weights in every calling.

Comment: + please read first paragraph of this : http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/control-random-number-streams.html#btms9o_ . This will say we have different stream in every worker !

Comment: The link is describing the default behavior. I'm describing to you how to change that default behavior to do what you asked. Your comment about "the random number generator of neural network" is confused. Neural networks do not have their own random number generator. `rng` is not a random number generator, it is a command used to modify the current random number generator and get information about it.

Comment: Thank you again. what is problem of default behavior? If all workers are using separate but equal generator why i have different outputs for `randperm(10)`in `parfor`? the sequence of outputs should be same in a specific worker and equal to other workers. Is that true? (suppose that a `ranperm` function in a `parfor` loop. I'm running it of 8 workers so i should have same output from every worker in every calling,is that true?)

Comment: The default behavior is for each worker to use a combined multiple recursive generator, but each worker will start with its RNG in a different state, so `randperm` will give different results on each worker. What I'm describing to you in my answer is how _you_ can directly control the state of the RNG on each worker, and ensure that they are all independent, reproducible, and have the correct statistical properties.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments. Neural network `configure` use `initnw` function for weight initialization in my code in `parfor` (some part of it is random). What do you think about it? Is this a problem? How we can control the behavior of it? (if you think this a good question i can add another question to stack overflow). Can we add these sub-streams to all random genegator functions in `parfor` with a function?

Comment: Under the hood, `initnw` just call `rand`, `randn` etc, which get random numbers from whatever is the global random number stream. You can set this with `RandStream.setGlobalStream`. So you would create the RNG with parallel substreams as above, then use `parfor i=1:4; RandStream.setGlobalStream(s{i}); % NN stuff; end`.

Comment: +another tiny question :-) : I'm calling these functions from another m-file (run out of parallel). So i don't want initialize rand-stream again and again from beginning. Can i continue it from previews end position? How can i do this?

Comment: +another tiny question :-) : I'm calling these functions from another m-file (run out of parallel). So i don't want initialize rand-stream again and again from beginning. Can i continue it from previews end position? How can i do this? (this is cost function of another process,I'm calling it again and again).

Comment: At any time you can retrieve the state of the current global random number stream using `st = rng`. Later you can say `rng(st)`, which will set the global stream to exactly what it was earlier, and the random numbers will repeat after that.

Comment: So i should save all `s{i}` and return it to `parfor` loop in next calling with `rng(--)` or I should save `rng` in every loop and return it using rng(saved_rng)? How can i do that in your proposed codes?

Comment: I would suggest that now is the time for you to take some of the above suggestions, try them out, play with them, get a good understanding of how they behave, and perhaps read through the documentation in detail. Then decide exactly what you want to achieve with relation to your neural network project, and if you have further difficulties, ask another specific question. I hope I've helped so far.

Comment: I added new related question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789035/set-and-get-randstream-in-matlab-parfor-loops?lq=1

Comment: Why you set Seed to `shuffle`? . please see end of this page : http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/reproducibility-in-parallel-statistical-computations.html#bso_x7w . What is this function : `paroptions = statset('UseParallel',true,'Streams',s)` . We need that in your proposed structure?

Comment: I set the seed to `shuffle` because you wanted to have new random numbers rather than have them be the same each time. If you don't want that, set the seed to something specific. The command `statset` is used to create options that you can pass directly into some commands from Statistics Toolbox, telling them how you want to deal with random number generation. If you're not using those commands from Statistics Toolbox, it is not necessary.